# Convert UTC time in 12 hours format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a discord bot. There is function in that bot, which returns when the member has joined the server. But the time is in **UTC** format. I just want to convert that UTC time in 12 hour clock format also using the UTC time zone of my country.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to format date string.

```
datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-d %I:%S %p") #2020-09-09 11:54 AM
```

%I for 12 hour time format and %p to display AM or PM

You can refere datetime docs for more understanding

You can also add %z or %Z to display timezone as per your requirement